# Process an HTML Form without the Submit Button Using VeeValidate

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vee-validate

I've created a [form handler using its composable](https://vee-validate.logaretm.com/v4/guide/composition-api/handling-forms) inside my `<script setup>`:

```
const { submitForm, resetForm, handleSubmit, meta } = useForm()

function save() {
  // Here I want to submit the form

  submitForm() // This doesn't work
  showSaveSnackbar.value = false
}

function discard() {
  resetForm()
  showSaveSnackbar.value = false
}

const onSubmit = handleSubmit(values => {
  // pretty print the values object
  alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
});
```

And in my template I wrote this:

```
<form @submit="onSubmit">
    <!-- inputs -->

</form>
```

I made a snackbar with a button that shows up (using [useForm's `meta.dirty`](https://vee-validate.logaretm.com/v4/api/use-form#composable-api) attribute). When I edit the form and I want to submit it, I want to use this custom button instead of the HTML Form's Submit button (in this case the button calls the custom `save()` function).

I tried using the `submitForm()` function but without success.

How can I do this?

Comment: Is a snackbar showing up or an alert? It looks like the `onSubmit` function is bound to the HTML form submit function. The `onSubmit` triggers an alert.

Comment: @Jason Sorry, I wrote the last part of the question wrong. Just edited it.

Comment: When you submit your HTML form, which JavaScript method do you want to execute?

Comment: @Jason I don't have a submit button in my form so at the moment there's no way to submit the form because I want to make it submittable only from the button located in the snackbar.

Comment: Have you tried binding the `save` function to the button in the snackbar?

Comment: @Jason Yes, the `save` function is bound to the button's `click` event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can handle the form processing in the `save` function (and possibly remove the `onSubmit` function).

```
const { errors, values } = useForm();

const save = () => {
  showSaveSnackbar.value = false
  alert(JSON.stringify(values.value, null, 2));
};
```

Comment: And to handle validation? Do I need to put just a check to see if the form is valid before "submitting" the form?

Comment: @alex3025 the `userForm` hook also exposes errors (`errors.value`).